# objective-c how to programatically landscape keyboard when device rotates

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, frame, uikeyboard

I have a `UIWebWiew` in a `UIViewController` that I want be able to be in landscapemode.
That is done.
But the keyboard gets stuck still in portraitmode when a textfield is taped.

So I added the redpart of the code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

Because I read that with that the keyboard will decide itself how to rotate. But that did nothing.

Any one got ideas on how I should do?

[image]

Comment: If you want your view controller to be just in landscape mode add -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate method and return YES just for landscape.

Comment: Well, I want for the user to be able to tilt the phone to left and get landscapemode.
I added and had also tried before the -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate method but it didnt give me any result with the keyboard with the -(void)didRotate

And no result with the tilt even without the -(void)didRotate